# Why wagtail rich text content not being displayed in the front-end in the way expected?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail, richtext

I am using wagtail Rich Text Field to create content for my website

`paragraph = RichTextField()`

However, I am getting an issue where lists are not being displayed in the front-end and the font color of the content written as rich text is different from the rest of the content. Is there something that I am doing wrong or may there be something I must do such that the The rich text content is displayed the way I write it in the admin panel and such that the rich text content is displayed with the same font color and size as the rest of the content?

I have used the *richtext* filter in my template: `{{ block.value|richtext }}`

How I entered the content:

[admin panel where i entered content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Coo7.png)

How content was displayed:

[how content is being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IgGu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser developer tools to see what is providing the styling for those items. My bet is that you have a CSS reset that is removing the regular browser styles but you are not adding them back in your front end CSS.